# Linux C process communication

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, mkfifo

I got school project in which I need to write a program that forks to 3 child process and they need to communicate:

```
stdin --> PID1 ---fifo---> PID2 ---file---> PID3 ---> stdout
```

CH2 translates that data to hex string. I also need to implement pause for whole program. My question is: do I need to implement synchronization mechanisms such as semaphores?

Comment: Yes, you need - for the PID2->PID3 stage. A fifo is self-synchronized, but a file is not.